# Advise on on-prem server alerts using azure log analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

Trying to set up alerts to inform us when a server is offline using azure log analytics. I have the monitor agent installed on all machines within the business but how would I configure this. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log) document to learn regarding seting up and configuring alerts using alerts interface in Azure portal. And the query in the alert to track when server is offline can be written by leveraging tables like 'Heartbeat' or 'Perf' with 'Uptime' counter name or 'Event', etc. Hope this helps!